# Parameters on LIMIT and OFFSET not working

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, coldbox

Im trying to implement pagination by parameterized my limit from request URL unfortunately I'm having error.

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''25'' at line 1`

Here is the code for sql syntax. Need your help badly.
`queryExecute("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT :limit",{limit:rc.limit});`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `limit` parameter is being passed as a string by default, whereas the database requires an integer value. Try specifying the type:

```
queryExecute("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT :limit",{limit:{value:rc.limit,sqltype:"integer"}});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! You've been a big help. I'm a beginner.